# Is the structure $(\mathbb{R}, +, *)$ rigid?

Tags: model-theory

Does the structure $(\mathbb{R}, + ,*)$ have only the trivial automorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\phi\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{R})$.
$$\phi(1)^2 = \phi(1) \implies \phi(1) = 1 $$
since $\phi$ is an automorphism. It's easy to see that for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, $\phi(x) = x.$ For $x> 0$
$$\phi(x) = \phi(\sqrt{x})^2> 0. $$
So $$ x>y \implies \phi(x)>\phi(y).$$
If $x$ is irrational, there exists $2$ sequences, one increasing $x_n$, and one decreasing $y_n$, both are sequences of rational numbers, and converge to $x$.
$$y_n = \phi(y_n)\geq \phi(x)\geq \phi(x_n) = x_n $$
By taking limit, $\phi(x) =x$ for all $x$.

Comment: @stressedout There's no continuity involved

Comment: @stressedout You only apply limits to $y_n\geq\phi(x)\geq x_n$.